# jQuery add and remove class dynamically on link click

Tags: jquery

I tried to add and remove a class on an HTML element using jQuery. It successfully adds the class, but the page link in my navbar didn't take me to the related page. How to solve this problem? Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqeelpld/7yydg1nt/) and script:

```
$('li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: I think `e.preventDefault();` is hindering the link to open.

Comment: thanks for reply, but if i remove that then it didn't even add  the class at all!

Comment: Please explain: As soon as you click a link, you want it to change color to stand out from the other links, but also open the link in the same page? Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for reply! Yes i exactly want that. if i include this e.preventDefault();  in my script then it changes clicked link color but didn't follow the related link and if i remove this from my script then links color didn't change and related links works fine as normal as i click them. remember i used my navigation as dynamically across all my pages with php.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use e.preventDefault()? Remove that line and it should start working

That call will keep the default method from being triggered, which in this case is the link out to your page http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: but if i remove that bit of code then it didn't even add the class at all!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by adding the class, but redirecting them to another page?

Comment: no! the reason why i add class is to keep the current link unique from others. e.g. change the link color, change the background color.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following code:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

As this is the main factor which stops the link to fire.

Comment: but if i remove that bit of code then it didn't even add the class at all!

Comment: it should add the class...but the link wont be triggered as long as you keep `e.preventDefault();` in your code.
Because `e.preventDefault();` only controls the event of the anchor tag that you want to click.

Comment: maybe i have some other issue but believe me when i remove the link its take me to the related page but with no class adding!

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Actually the class is added to the link but the way you have written the html code makes the link redirection which gives the feeling as if the classes has not been added to the anchor tag.

Comment: try adding `target='_blank'` to every anchor that you have and remove the `e.preventDefault();`. Then you'll know what i am saying. Try it out.

Comment: after adding target='_blank' every link opens in new tab in browser and class is only apply on original window not on newly opened page although it opened the related page from the link!

Comment: by checking in firebug class is added to the anchor tag for half a second then removes back after removing this guy from script  e.preventDefault();